# Noob trying to create a Cocoapod - not very successfully

Tags: cocoapods

Sorry for the Noob question, but I'm having trouble figuring out how all this is put together.

I created a pod with pod lib create.  I now have the directory structure, and have placed my classes into Pod/Classes.

It *sounds like* from the doc, I should run pod install or pod update to be able to use my pod in development mode.  I'm expecting it would create the symlinks mentioned in how to use the Development Pod.

I'm kinda stuck here - what am I missing?  How do I start working in Xcode to test my library?

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact problem? Post your project structure. In order to develop and debug your pod library you need sample also with your pod installed over it. So you need podfile

Comment: I was hoping to be able to work on the Pod in the Pod structure WITHOUT having to deploy it.  It seems like that's impossible, unless I'm missing something.  I have recently noticed that you can point to a point on the filesystem while using a Pod in a project.  That seems like the best/only way to go.  Correct?  And thanks for responding!

Comment: yes, you need a project to install pod to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your Example project with

```
pod lib create MyLib
```

CocoaPods creates two folders, one called `Example`, and `Pod`, first one is where your **demo app** goes, the one which get's downloaded with `pod try MyLib`. `Pod` folder is the one where your **pod files go**, `Pod/Classes` for .h and .m, `Pod/Assets` for images, nibs and other resources.

```
- [MyLib]
-- [Example] // demo project
--- MyLib.xcworkspace
-- [Pod]     // pod files, Podspec is looking at
--- [Classes] // .h, .m
--- [Assets]  // resources, .png/.xib etc
-- Podspec
```

Also it creates Podspec for your lib, you should edit it so it includes correct info, by default it's configured to use all .h/.m from `Pod/Classes` and .png from `Pod/Assets`. That's important, because your demo project in `Example` folder depends on it.

After all this details, the solution:

1. Open MyLib.xcworkcpace
2. a) Expand groups/files tree at Project Navigator up to `Pods/Development Pods/MyLib`, right click on MyLib, **Add files to "Pods"...**, add some .h/.m to `Pod/Classes`(that's important).
   ...**or**...
   b) Manually copy some .h/.m to `Pod/Classes`.
3. In terminal go to Example folder and update pods:

   `cd MyLib/Example
   pod update`
4. Now you can import those files with `#import <someFile.h>`.

### How does this work?

CocoaPods uses your Podspec which tells it to get files from `Pod/Classes` and symlink it to Pods project of your `Example/MyLib` project. In the Podfile generated for example project you can see this line:

```
target 'MyLib', :exclusive => true do
  pod "MyLib", :path => "../"
end
```

Note the `:path` keyword, this means, that pod `MyLib` will be locally fetched from the podspec at path using the rules inside it and **don't mess with the remote source**. In other words it will find your Podspec, investigate that required files are at `Pod/Classes` and instead of fetching your git repository it will just symlink them to your Pods project. So you can edit them as you wish and do as much `pod update` as you wish, as it just symlinks the files you've edited. The only thing is that if you add more files you need to `pod update` so they'll be symlinked and added to appropriate pod targets.

Note that CocoaPods creates "Pods" project which has a target for each referenced pod, all .m files from pods are compiled to .a files and linked to your app binary, header (.h) files are aggregated to folders via symlink and that folders are appended to **Other C flags**, so they're available via `#import <%header%.h>`. That's why you won't find any .m symlinks for pods declared with ":path" keyword, as .m files are referenced directly at their locations by Pods project targets.

Comment: Thank you!  I had figured out the top part finally, but still hadn't gotten to the :path stuff.  Fantastic!